# Translating student distribution parameters from ```fitdist``` into degrees of freedom

Tags: r, distribution

I've used `fitdist` from `rugarch` to find the best student distribution for my data:

```
> fitdist(distribution = 'std', sp500_logreturns)$pars
          mu        sigma        shape 
0.0008121004 0.0113748869 2.3848231857
```

The reason using this function instead of `fitdistr` is it fits my data so much better. But is there some way to "translate" this into degree of freedom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `X` is a Student random variable with `nu` degrees of freedom, then `std` is the distribution of `mu + lambda*X` with `shape = nu` and `sigma = lambda*sqrt(nu/(nu-2))`:

```
library(rugarch)

set.seed(666)

lambda <- 4
sims <- 1 + lambda * rt(20000, df = 5)

fitdist(distribution = 'std', sims)$pars
#       mu    sigma    shape 
# 1.033717 5.146754 4.916808

lambda * sqrt(5/(5-2))
# 5.163978
```

Comment: Is it always shape = degree of freedom? Because if I run two different simulations with one using "shape" and the other using "degree of freedom" I get nothing alike (I know it's a simulation, but still)..